# How to pass data from Service to Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I am calling broadcast receiver from service through this method.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(NotifyService.this, AlarmReciever.class);
   intent.putExtra("TIME",ttime);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(),    34324243, intent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timee,pendingIntent);
```

In Broadcastreceiver page I am receiveing through this method.

```
   Bundle b = in.getExtras();   
   date = b.getString("TIME");
```

Problem is In Broadcastreceiver page I am getting null value.
My Question is :-

How to pass data from service to broadcastreceiver ?

Answer (score 2):

In your main activity start your service as

```
i = new Intent(this, SimpleService.class);
startService(i);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SimpleService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
```

use send broadcast to send any value from service class to mainactiviy class as

```
intent.putExtra("textval", s);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and then in your main activity class receive it as

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //do your coding here using intent
        }

    };
```

Comment: But I am directly calling it from service, not using activity

Answer (score 0):

**OK i assume  the "ttime" is  a bundle (  from the  code  your  wrote it seems  to make  sense)**

Try and  recieve the  data  like  this

```
   Bundle b=  in.getBundleExtra("TIME");
```

In case the "tttime" is  of  other format  say a  String  or Int   you can  get the  data  in onReceive of Broadcastreceiverlike this

String :

```
in.getStringExtra("TIME");
```

Integer :

```
in.getIntExtra("TIME", -1) // -1 is  default value  which  will be  return incase  no matching integer  found with the key "TIME" in intent "in"
```

For  full details and  how to get data from  intent  of different type  refer to [android  documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

you missed to do like this:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NotifyService.this, AlarmReciever.class);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You can call pendingIntent Like this:-

```
    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Service.this,
            0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),5* 60 * 1000, operation);
```

If you are passing any time data to broadcast class,then you can receive that data in receiver class as

```
String mTime = NotifyService.time;
```

Try this. Inform me also.